Sobolev space $W^{1,2}$ embeds into $L^\infty$ in 2-dim unit ball

Let $B$ be the 2-dim unit ball, $u \in W^{1,2}_0(B)$, $u\ge0$ is the weak solution of $-\Delta u=f(u)$ where $|f(t)|\le|t|$.
Prove: $||u||_{L^\infty(B)} \le C ||u||_{L^2(B)}$.

I have no idea about how to estimate $L^\infty$ norm. The sobolev embedding for $p=n(=2)$ doesn't hold for $q=\infty$. If $u \in W^{1,3}$ then the $p>n$ case works here, but can it to be true?
Any comments or solutions will be full appreciated!

Using the $L^\infty$-regularity for the elliptic equation, one gets $\|u\|_{L^\infty(B)} \le c \|f(u)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$, which is less than $c \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$.
Reference:
G. Stampacchia. “Le problème de Dirichlet pour les équations el-
liptiques du second ordre à coefficients discontinus”. In: Ann. Inst.
Fourier (Grenoble) 15.fasc. 1 (1965), pp. 189–258.

Any chance you have a reference in english?

iirc this result is also in the Kinderlehrer & Stampacchia book.
